# How to submit a case from ISV developer org?

Tags: isv, support, developer-org

I tried to find a link to submit a case requesting enabling person account but did not find a link in my ISV developer org. Any thoughts please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't submit cases from any developer org. Use your primary ISV org to submit cases, or submit them through the Partner Portal.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I can use primary ISV org to submit a case. But how can i submit a case to enable person account for the free developer org? Please advice. Thanks again.